# csrf cookie not set

Tags: django, apache, django-rest-framework

Я знаю, что этот вопрос довольно популярный, прежде чем задавать его, я изучил все предыдущие вопросы и ответы на них, но так и не нашел решение для себя.

Моя проблема в том, что я пытаюсь удалить полностью проверку `csrftoken` в своем приложении. Я понимаю уязвимости, открывающиеся в данном случае, но это для меня не критично. Во время разработки никаких ошибок на моем компе в связи с `csrftoken` не происходит, я разрабатываю на `windows`, но при запуске его на сервере `apache linux` эта ошибка появляется **и только при редактировании уже существующей записи** (при создании новой, проблем нет), мне трудно представить причину, по которой это происходит только на сервере `apache linux`, перенос я осуществляю с помощью `docker`.

К удалению `csrftoken` из своего приложения я пришел по той же самой причине, на компьютере на `windows`, на котором я разрабатывал приложение, ошибок при включенном `csrftoken` не происходило, но при переносе на сервер `apache linux`, формы, использующие передачу данных с помощью `js` файлов, также выдавали ошибку `403`.

**Settings**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
]

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
```

**Во всех формах `html`** я закомментировал `csrf_token`

```
{#                        {% csrf_token %}#}
```

**В файлах js** я закомментировал `headers`

```
// headers: {'X-CSRFToken': document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value},
```

В атрибут формы добавил `action=""`

Я  уже очистил файл `cookie`, использовал другой браузер, но ошибка так и остается. В браузере `Edge` дополнительно почистил `socket` и `dns` с помощью следующей команды: `edge://net-internals/#sockets`.

Дополнительно я специально сделал ошибку в программе, для того чтобы django сформировал отчет, в результате я обнаружил на сервере `apache linux` следующую информацию (отличительной особенностью является то, что эта информация отсутствует на локальной машине, на которой я разрабатываю проект, на `windows`):

```
CSRF_COOKIE = 'ijijj34j24345678x6gfddsfvgnkjnhkhkhfd6'
CSRF_COOKIE_USED = True
```

Я попытался передать указанный параметр `CSRF_COOKIE_USED` в файле `settings.py`:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_USED = False
```

но это не привело к желаемому результату.

**Я попробовал добавить декоратор**, но это не привело к желаемому результату:

```
class EventCard(CreateView):
    template_name = 'main/event_card.html'

    @csrf_exempt
    def get(self, request, Id_Events=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моя ошибка заключалась в том, что при включенной сессии происходит неявное добавление csrf токена, даже когда он везде выключен.

Для решения задачи, я использовал следующий ответ:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458166/how-to-disable-djangos-csrf-validation/70732475#70732475